# Error application/x-www-form-urlencoded is not supported when sending curl requests to elastic search server

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I am trying to post some data to an elastic search server. I am using curl for this. The code is:

```
curl -X PUT https://username:password@someurl:443/index_name?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d  ' {"mappings": {"properties": {"my_field": {"type": "search_as_you_type"}}}}'
```

only the basic stuff of retrieving index info via  `cat/_indices?v` works

Errors include

```
"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported", curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message is clear that you are using the wrong content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, in very first line of error message.

> "Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not
>   supported",

As given mapping seems to be copied from the official ES https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/search-as-you-type.html link, there only you can find the corresponding CURL format.

Pasting that format as well as screen-shot from the link, how can you copy the entire curl command.

[image: copy as curl in circle]
 here and I tried it in my local and it worked, note the only difference is content type which should be `application/json`

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9500/so_index?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_field": {
        "type": "search_as_you_type"
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Comment: I have copy pasted the code as mentioned in the docs. Doesn't work even on the local machine

Comment: The first part gets executed and an index is created. But the mapping is not created.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal can u share error msg which u getting?

Comment: when i run it in python, I get the following error: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {properties={my_field={type=string}}}]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {properties={my_field={type=string}}}]"},"status":400}

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after some trial and error. Here is the code used (after creating the index).

```
import requests
import json
url = 'http://localhost:9200/companies_list/_mapping'
headers1 = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
data_obj = {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        }
      }
  }

response = requests.put(url, headers=headers1, data=json.dumps(data_obj))
print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful commands for people starting out on elasticsearch or upgrading to the latest version

```
import requests
import json

headers1 = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}

#create index
url = 'http://localhost:9200/my_index'
response = requests.put(url)

#view indexes
url = 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
response = requests.get(url)

#create mappings. if mappings are not created, then dynamic mapping will be created by elastic search
url = 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping'
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers1, data=json.dumps(data_obj))

data_obj = {
      "properties": {
        "names": {
          "type":   "search_as_you_type",
        }
      }
  }

#insert data. if mappings have not been created initially, then dynamic mapping will be created by elastic search
url = 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_doc/'
my_list = ['test name 1', 'test name 2', 'test name 3']
for i,j in enumerate(my_list):
    response = requests.post(url+str(i), headers=headers1, data=json.dumps({"names":j}))
    print(response.content)


#retrieve data. 
url = 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_doc/_search'
url = 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search' #works with both

data_obj =  {
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "test name 2",
      "fields": [
        "names",
        "names._2gram",
        "names._3gram"
      ]
    }
  }
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers1, data=json.dumps(data_obj))
print(response.content)
x = json.loads(response.content)
#x = json.loads(response.content.decode("utf-8")) #in case the response is in bytes and not str
for i in x["hits"]["hits"]:
    print(i["_source"]["names"], i["_score"])
```

I am new to elastic search. Will keep updating the post with more basics